# How to create functions return some explicit types, and some implicit ones?

Tags: typescript

Given the code below,

```
function system(): ISavable & ISerializable {
    return {
        num: 1, // error!

        save() {},
        load() {},

        serialize() {},
        deserialize() {},
    }
}

interface ISavable {
    save: () => void
    load: () => void
}

interface ISerializable {
    seriailze: () => void
    deserialize: () => void
}
```

[Playground link →](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwJ7KgUwLYAoCUAXIgJIDKAhgG4UBGANpogGSlmYBOMF9MAXnUaIA3gFgAUIimIOmKCA5Ixk6arAhsxAIwAaCRNWrk1TAREBfPSsOJ6cCgBMzwy-uuHknbrz6n8FqxspB0xPLh5+PwCDaXMJOPEJGDAsDmAKCCZyakEmZSMTYjMAXgA+RCo4GAcYqTtHIv8yiqqa8QSklM50zLYvCIEGPNqUfph6X0bEZsrqkZCw70ipmdb4oA)

#### The problem

When returning property `num: 1`, TypeScript complains it is not specified by either `ISavable` or `ISerializable`—and that's expected.

One possible solution would be creating one extra type that exposes all the stuff this function is going to return—but I'm looking for something that allows me to go implicit when it comes to the function's unique properties.

To make myself even clearer, when you don't specify the return of your function, the type of it is inferred and you get autocomplete, etc. I want that plus to be able to infer the types and guarantee some explicitly specified properties are returned as well.

#### Question

I'd like to type the return of my function in a way where it requires the function to return the properties from both interfaces (`ISavable` and `ISerializable`), but still allows me to return extra properties freely, that may be unique to this function.

That said,

1. Is it possible?
2. If so, how?

---

*I think my needs can be achieved through classes, but I'm pursuing a solution specifically for functions.*

Comment: doesn't 'this function returns X & Y, but also some unknown amount of extra stuff' contradict the whole idea of strict typing?  That said nothing stops you having a container of known type and then putting other stuff in *that*.

Comment: You are right. However, the problem is that I haven't made myself clear enough. I'd like to have some explicit returns and some implicit ones.

Comment: Then what's wrong with 1. having a container type (e.g. a 'value' with a 'name' and 'content: any'), or 2. just using JS if you don't actually *want* to be strict about typing?

Comment: Do you just want the error "to go away" or do you also want the return type of the function to include the additional properties?

Comment: @2e0byo If you write a function and are not explicit about its return type, the type is inferred. I'd like to keep inferring the type, even when I say "this function must return these properties, and the other ones are up to it".

Comment: @TobiasS. I'd like the additional properties to be included as well. As if it was inferring them.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge ah right, I'd misread 'implicit' here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach:

The desire to create objects which *satisify* a type while still maintaining  their own literal type is not new. There is already a [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46827) to add a `satisfies` operator to the language. But until it is added, we can create our own "operator".

```
const satisfies = <T,>() => <S extends T>(arg: S) => arg
```

This generic function can be used inside `system`.

```
function system() {
    return satisfies<ISavable & ISerializable>()({
        num1: 1,
        num2: 2,

        save() {},
        load() {},

        serialize() {},
        deserialize() {},
    })
}

system().num1
system().num2
```

The `satisfies` function ensures that the constraint is fulfilled and extra properties are allowed and will be observable in the return type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwJ7KgUwLYAoCUiA3gLABQiliATplCNUsgIazLAybIA8AkgMrMAbswBGAG0yIAZIgGZqMZuJgAvMZIB8BXKQpUDYENgCMALkQmANOQOHjAJgsObZW3coshmAsQC%20rh6U4nDMACa%20RAHk7h7ICkoqqj6EUYFBYVwJymop-umUfvjkfjFkEAgYKKww7JzIiAC8iNwAKlbahI2aLfyImAAeWGBhDa3azNQA5hb8XT2TU2UwYFjUwMwQUgLCGlJ6Bl6YFr7diEJwMGGxiCHhJ-Pnl9dkpW5kK2sbW3L82Ul7Yg3eKKHLJB5NHoXK43TIgxK5CFnaEvN7kNAYHAEAB0RlM6PQWDw%20FxjiAA)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the cleanest solution I can imagine to this problem was
found by the OP, (loosely) based on an answer I hasted to post
and then deleted as I realized it was seriously lacking; for
what it's worth, his was posted as a message to my first answer, before
the fine solution by Tobias.

```ts
function system() {
    const ret: ISavable & ISerializable = {
        save() {},
        load() {},

        serialize() {},
        deserialize() {},
    }

    return { num: 100, ...ret }
}

interface ISavable {
    save: () => void
    load: () => void
}

interface ISerializable {
    serialize: () => void
    deserialize: () => void
}

system().num
```

---

Inspired by the solution of Tobias, I tried to find a version
that:

- has zero effect in the generated javascript code,
- produces a more relevant TS error message when the
  `ISavable & ISerializable` extension requirement is not met.

The best version I could come up with is this:

```ts
type ExtendsP<I, T extends I> = T

function system(){
    return {
        num: 100,

        save() {},
        load() {},

        serialize() {},
        deserialize() {},
    };
}

type _ = ExtendsP<() => ISavable & ISerializable, typeof system>

interface ISavable {
    save: () => void
    load: () => void
}

interface ISerializable {
    serialize: () => void
    deserialize: () => void
}

system().num
```

It is somewhat awkward and might result in a linter warning for
the lack of use of type `_` (I doubt many ts linters are familiar
with the convention for `_` in js), but I hope someone might find
something relevant for their similar issues.